# Database Table Referencing Several Records

Tags: database, primary-key, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I'm looking for some guidance as to how to set up a database I am creating.  I think the best way to ask the question is to describe the specific scenario:

I have a database that will hold information about student-employees at a school.

I have one table called "Semesters" that contains information about a specific semester (e.g. "Fall/Spring/Summer", year, etc.).

I have another table called "Employees" that contains information about a specific student-employee (e.g. name, jobTitle, startDate, endDate).  I would also like to have a reference to the "Semesters" table indicating which semester(s) the employee was hired.  So, for example, one column in the "Employees" table would tell me that this specific employee was working during the "Fall2010, Spring2011, and Fall2011" semesters.

The problem is that I don't know how to reference several records in one field.

I am sure that this is a fairly common scenario, I'm just not sure how to go about it.
Answers that reference MS Access or SqlServer would be excellent.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment. If so you might add that tag. It's common to use a linking table between two entities to create a many to many relationship.

Comment: Not homework, just a project I'm working on - building a simple app for my school paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a many to many relationship. In such a case you would likely utilize a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

**Employees** (empID, name)

```
1 bob
2 moe
3 george
```

**Semesters** (semID, name)

```
1 fall 2010
2 spring 2010
```

**EmploymentHistory** (empID & semID)

```
1 1 (bob was employed fall 2010)
1 2 (bob was employed spring 2010)
2 2 (moe was employed fall 2010)
```

Comment: I get it now. Never heard of a junction table, but I should have thought of this. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing, best of luck with your project!

Comment: Wiki is evidently written by unqualified and inexperienced people, who learn as they go; they use all kinds of adorable names for technical items that have one name.  The Relational term for a table that hosts a many-to-many relation only (just the two FKs) is **Associative** Table.  If it contains data, it is just a table; in IDEF1X terms, a **Dependent** table.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with several foreign keys to the Semester table (not Semesters) from the Employee table (not Employees).

If you want to keep track of the semesters that an Employee has worked, I'd normalize that into a WorkHistory table that's one-to-many with Employee and many-to-many with Semester.